# MySQL Multiple Case When Exists Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables. Let's call it: SEATS and SEAT_ALLOCATION_RULE table.

Below are the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SEATS` (
  `SeatID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SeatName` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`SeatID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

INSERT INTO `SEATS` (`SeatID`, `SeatName`) VALUES
(1, 'Super VIP'),
(2, 'VIP'),
(3, 'Business'),
(4, 'Economy'),
(5, 'Standing');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SEAT_ALLOCATION_RULE` (
 `SeatID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Origin` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Destination` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `Passenger_Type` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`SeatID`,`Origin`,`Destination`,`Passenger_Type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `SEAT_ALLOCATION_RULE` (`SeatID`, `Origin`, `Destination, `Passenger_Type`) VALUES
(1, 'Malaysia','',''),
(2, 'Malaysia','Singapore',''),
(3, 'Malaysia','Singapore','Senior_Citizen'),
(4, 'Bangkok','Japan','Student'),
(5, 'Cambodia','China','Senior_Citizen');
```

SEAT_ALLOCATION_RULE table determines which seat should a passenger be assigned to based on the following order in priority:

```
1. Origin, destination, and  passenger_type match
2. Origin and destination match
3. Origin match
```

It means that if all the fields (origin, destination, and passenger_type) match, it should take higher priority than if it is just two fields match and so on. If a column is empty, it is considered as unspecified and hence has lower priority. So, for example:

- If the Origin is Malaysia, Destination is Singapore, and Passenger_Type is Senior_Citizen, it should return seatID 3
- If the Origin is Malaysia, Destination is Singapore, and Passenger_Type is Student, it should return seatID 2 (since it only match Origin and Destination)
- If the Origin is Malaysia, Destination is US, and Passenger_Type is Student, it should return seatID 1 (since it only match Origin).

Now, based on the rules above, if the origin is Malaysia, destination is Singapore, and Passenger_Type is student, the query to return seatID is as follow:

```
SELECT s.SeatID, s.SeatName
FROM SEATS s
WHERE
CASE WHEN EXISTS(
  select 1
  from SEAT_ALLOCATION_RULE r
  where s.SeatID = r.SeatID
  AND r.Origin = 'Malaysia'
  AND r.Destination = 'Singapore'
  AND r.Passenger_Type='Student') Then 1
WHEN EXISTS(
  select 1
  from SEAT_ALLOCATION_RULE r
  where s.SeatID = r.SeatID
  AND r.Origin = 'Malaysia'
  AND r.Destination = 'Singapore'
  AND r.Passenger_Type='') Then 1
WHEN EXISTS(
  select 1
  from SEAT_ALLOCATION_RULE r
  where s.SeatID = r.SeatID
  AND r.Origin = 'Malaysia'
  AND r.Destination = ''
  AND r.Passenger_Type='') Then 1 END
```

However, the query above does not work as it will return seatID 1 and 2, but the expected output is only seatID 2 (since origin and destination matches and it takes higher precedence). Can someone help to correct my SQL query?

Comment: You seem to be missing a `Passengers` table (or similar).

Comment: The `CASE` produces a `1` value or NULL. The `WHERE` clause needs a boolean expression. You need to compare this result to something.

Comment: Also: how should we break a tie. If there is, say, an additional rule for `('Malaysia', '', 'Student')` , how would that work with a Student traveling from Malaysia to Singapore? That passenger matches two factors from two rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
select seatid
  from seat_allocation_rule sar
order by ((sar.origin = :origin) << 2) + ((sar.destination = :destination) << 1) + (sar.passenger_type = :passenger_type) desc,
         ((sar.origin <> '')     << 2) + ((sar.destination <> '')          << 1) + (sar.passenger_type <> '')             asc
 limit 1
```

To understand how:

```
create table testcase (
    origin         varchar(255),
    destination    varchar(255),
    passenger_type varchar(255),
    expected_seat  int(11)
);

insert into testcase values ('Malaysia','Singapore','Senior_Citizen',3),
                            ('Malaysia','Singapore','Student',2),
                            ('Malaysia','US','Student',1);

select * from (
select tc.*,
       sar.seatid,
       case when sar.seatid = tc.expected_seat then 'Y' else '-' end as pass,
         ((sar.origin = tc.origin) << 2)
       + ((sar.destination = tc.destination) << 1)
       + ((sar.passenger_type = tc.passenger_type) << 0) as score,
         ((sar.origin <> '') << 2)
       + ((sar.destination <> '') << 1)
       + ((sar.passenger_type <> '') << 0) as priority
  from seat_allocation_rule sar
       cross join testcase tc
) x order by expected_seat desc, score desc, priority asc;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I need.. A very clever trick to use the bitwise operator!

Answer (score 0):

This fixes the existing SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.SeatID, s.SeatName
FROM SEATS s
LEFT JOIN SEAT_ALLOCATION_RULE r  ON r.SeatID = s.SeatID
    AND r.Origin = 'Malaysia' 
    AND ( 
       (r.Destination = 'Singapore' AND r.Passenger_Type IN ('Student', ''))
       OR 
       (r.Destination = '' AND r.Passenger_Type = '')
    )
WHERE r.SeatID IS NOT NULL
```

But it's only a partial solution, and it's hand-coding logic you really want to apply based solely on the data.

A complete solution will use hypothetical inputs for your passenger's ticket info to produce all eligible seats. This is a great use of lateral joins/apply, which are sadly lacking in MySql (all of their major competitors have had these for at least two release cycles, along with other gems that are absent from the current MySql release like windowing functions, ctes, full joins... I could go on). Here's how I'd do it in Sql Server:

```
SELECT p.PassengerID, s.SeatID, s.SeatName
FROM Passenger p
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 r.SeatID
    FROM SEAT_ALLOCATION_RULE r
    WHERE COALESCE(NULLIF(r.Origin, ''),p.Origin) = p.Origin
        AND COALESCE(NULLIF(r.Destination,''), p.Destination) = p.Destination
        AND COALESCE(NULLIF(r.Passenger_Type,''),p.Passenger_Type) = p.Passenger_Type
    ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN r.Origin <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      + CASE WHEN r.Destination <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      + CASE WHEN r.Passenger_Type <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
) r
INNER JOIN SEATS s ON s.SeatID = r.SeatID
WHERE p.PassengerID = /* passenger criteria here */
```

I know the Sql Server solution isn't much immediate help to you, but perhaps it will suggest a better MySql solution.

Without `APPLY`, the only way I know to do this is to first compute the MAX() match count for your passengers (how many parts of the rules match):

```
SELECT p.PassengerID, 
   MAX(CASE WHEN r.Origin <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      + CASE WHEN r.Destination <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      + CASE WHEN r.Passenger_Type <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MatchCount
FROM Passenger p
INNER JOIN SEAT_ALLOCATION_RULE r ON COALESCE(NULLIF(r.Origin, ''),p.Origin) = p.Origin
    AND COALESCE(NULLIF(r.Destination,''), p.Destination) = p.Destination
    AND COALESCE(NULLIF(r.Passenger_Type,''),p.Passenger_Type) = p.Passenger_Type
GROUP BY p.PassengerID
```

And then use that to filter down to results that have the same number of matches:

```
SELECT p
FROM Passenger p
INNER JOIN ( /* matchecounts */
    SELECT p.PassengerID, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN r.Origin <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          + CASE WHEN r.Destination <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          + CASE WHEN r.Passenger_Type <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MatchCount
    FROM Passenger p
    INNER JOIN SEAT_ALLOCATION_RULE r ON COALESCE(NULLIF(r.Origin, ''),p.Origin) = p.Origin
        AND COALESCE(NULLIF(r.Destination,''), p.Destination) = p.Destination
        AND COALESCE(NULLIF(r.Passenger_Type,''),p.Passenger_Type) = p.Passenger_Type
    GROUP BY p.PassengerID
) m ON m.PassengerID = p.PassengerID
INNER JOIN SEAT_ALLOCATION_RULE r ON COALESCE(NULLIF(r.Origin, ''),p.Origin) = p.Origin
    AND COALESCE(NULLIF(r.Destination,''), p.Destination) = p.Destination
    AND COALESCE(NULLIF(r.Passenger_Type,''),p.Passenger_Type) = p.Passenger_Type
INNER JOIN SEATS s ON s.SeatID = r.SeatID
WHERE m.MatchCount =  
    (CASE WHEN r.Origin <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN r.Destination <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN r.Passenger_Type <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  AND p.PassengerID = /* Passenger criteria here */
```

Which repeats a lot of code as well as effort in the DB, and is not very efficient. You can repeat the passenger criteria in the nested query, but that would only help a little. This option might also return multiple records for a passenger if they match two rules equally, though you can solve this easily enough with a GROUP BY expression.

In either case, note you can improve performance and simplify code by using actual `NULL` values instead of empty strings for missing parts of the `SEAT_ALLOCATION_RULE` table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although it works, but it is a bit complex.